# Qual a diferença entre *variável e *variável-'0'?

Tags: c, char

Estou escrevendo um jogo de Sudoku com `C` e `ncurses`, abaixo segue o código de uma função que recebe um ponteiro pra uma variável `(ch)` que armazena tecla digitada com a função `getch()`, se o número já existir horizontalmente, verticalmente ou no bloco retorna `false`, se não `true`.

Dúvida:

- No código, se substituir `*ch-'0'` por `*ch`, ele para de funcionar
  corretamente, retorna `false` somente em números adicionados pelo
  usuário, ignorando os padrões, o comportamento também muda conforme a
  posição do cursor. Por quê? Qual a diferença?

Código:

```
bool
num(int *ch)
{
    // g.y e g.x Armazenam a posição do cursor no array
    // g.r_board Array de referência
    if (g.r_board[g.y][g.x] > 0)
    {
        hide_banner(); // Esconde frase da tela
        show_banner("Número fixo"); // Mostra uma frase na tela
        show_cursor(); // Move o cursor pra posição original
        return false;
    }

    // Verifica se tem número igual na horizontal
    // g.board Array que armazena números do jogo
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (g.board[g.y][i] == (*ch-'0'))
        {
            hide_banner();
            show_banner("Número igual horizontal");
            show_cursor();
            return false;
        }

    // Verifica se tem número igual na vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        if (g.board[i][g.x] == (*ch-'0'))
        {
            hide_banner();
            show_banner("Número igual vertical");
            show_cursor();
            return false;
        }

    // Verifica se tem número igual dentro do bloco
    for (int i = (g.y/3)*3, j = i+3; i < j; i++)
        for (int k = (g.x/3)*3, l = k+3; k < l; k++)
            if (g.board[i][k] == (*ch-'0'))
            {
                hide_banner();
                show_banner("Número igual bloco");
                show_cursor();
                return false;
            }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto é a mesma coisa que fazer

```
*ch - 48
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Char/Arithmetic.c).

já `'0'` é um caractere que mostra o texto de um zero e equivalente ao código 48 em decimal da [tabela ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Ele não vale 0 como pode se pensar à primeira vista. Ele usou o tipo `char` porque é mais semântico para este código, mas a aritmética é definida em binário, não importa se tem um número um um caractere no seu código fonte.

Se o código pede uma subtração e você retira o resultado sairá errado.

Ele está pegando o código recebido recebido e subtraindo o caractere do zero para fazer com que o valor seja zerado, ou seja se digitou o caractere 0, você quer o número 0, então se o caractere 0 vale 48, você tem que subtrair 48 para atingir 0, que é o que aquela expressão faz de forma mais simples, você nem precisa saber que o caractere 0 vale 48 na tabela ASCII. O mesmo vale para os demais caracteres, se digitar o caractere 1, é claro que ele pegará o código 49, menos 48 do caractere 0 que está lá na expressão e dará o número 1.

Comment: Cheguei a este código na base tentativa-erro, escrevi vários. O curioso é que se escrever `*ch - 0`, `*ch`ou qualquer outra coisa que não seja `*ch-'0'` não funciona, não entendo por que, não faz sentido, lendo todo o código não faz sentido mesmo, `*ch` não deveria funcionar? Digo, está sendo comparado o valor inteiro dentro da variável com os valores inteiros do array.

Comment: Se você fizer `30 - 20` e quer o resultado `10`, se você fizer só `30` vai resultar em `10`?

Comment: Entendi, a função getch() armazena o número inteiro da tabela ascii e não o número literal, por exemplo, digito 1 e a função armazena 49 na variável. As documentações que li sobre esta função não diziam isso, por isso deixei passar despercebido.